# How to load tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("2-conv-0dense-128-units")
```

> model = tf.keras.models.load_model("2-conv-0dense-128-units.model")
> <-- OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at:
> 2-conv-0dense-128-units.model{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

I have a saved model at "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\bing\Bing\Python_App\Scripts\logs\2-conv-0dense-128-units" but I don't know how to load it using tensorflow

Comment: What format is your model saved as? h5?

Answer (score 0):

path can be relative or absolute, if former ensure that the saved model is inside the dir you're working in.

```
model = load_model('path where model was saved')
```

Comment: I changed it to:
model = load_model("C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\bing\Bing\Python_App\Scripts\logs\2-conv-0dense-128-units")

but it gave me an error:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

how do i fix this?

Comment: Change ur normal string to raw string by putting r before it like this:  r"C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\bing\Bing\Python_App..." or put it in this form: "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/bing/Bing/Python_App......"  or